# Búsqueda de un elemento en una Array por recursividad en Scala

Tags: scala

Buenas a todos acabo de empezar a usar Scala y tengo un problema del que no salgo, necesito encontrar un elemento dentro de un array por recursividad con una función auxiliar llamada buscar, que tome parámetros de los extremos izquierdos y derecho. La verdad que estoy muy agobiado por que el compilador no me tira ningún error, tan sólo parece que no entra del método busquedaBinariaRec cuando lo pongo en el println. Antes de nada, gracias por vuestra ayuda, esto es lo que tengo hasta ahora:

```
  import scala.io.StdIn._

def busquedaBinariaRec[A](x:A,xs:Array[A])(implicit ord : Ordering[A]): Any ={
  //implementarlos recursivamente sin usar bucles
  import ord._
  buscar(0, xs.length -1)
  def buscar (izq:Int, der:Int):Any = {
    var indice : Option[Int] = None
    var izq = 0
    var der = xs.length -1
    if (indice.isEmpty && izq <= der) {
      val cen = (izq+der)/2
      val y = xs(cen)
      if (x==y) indice=Some(cen)
      else if (x>y)
       izq = cen +1
      else
        der = cen-1
    }
   return indice 
  }

}
  println("¿Cual es el Array?")
val xs = Array[Int](1, 5, 6, 10, 14, 20, 50) //El Array sobre el que queramos realizar la busqueda lo cambiamos aqui
println(xs.mkString("Array(", ", ", ")"))
println("Introduce el elemento que quieras buscar")
val n: Int = readInt()
println(busquedaBinariaRec(n, xs))
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Un primer consejo**: aprovéchate del fabuloso sistema de tipos de scala. Nunca uses el tipo `Any` para retorno de una función si no quieres sorpresas luego.

La función `busquedaBinariaRec` retornará el resultado de la última sentencia, que es la definición de la función `buscar`, definición que resulta en un tipo `Unit`, que es lo que devuelve y que no imprime nada en el `println`.

Supongo que no es el resultado esperado, que lo que querías era que la función `buscar` se llamara a sí misma, recursivamente, y devolver el resultado final, el índice del elemento dentro del Array.

Si hubieras puesto el tipo de dato que devuelve, `Option[Int]`, te hubiera dado error en tiempo de compilación, antes de ejecutar nada.

La *signatura* de `busquedaBinariaRec` debería ser:

```scala
def busquedaBinariaRec[A](x:A, xs:Array[A])(implicit ord : Ordering[A]): Option[Int]
```

En cuanto a la definición de `buscar`, sería algo así:

```scala
def buscar (izq: Int, der: Int): Option[Int] = {
  if (izq > der)
    None
  else{
    val cen = (izq + der)/2
    val y = xs(cen)
    if (x == y)
      Some(cen)
    else if (x < y) 
      buscar(izq, cen-1)
    else
      buscar(cen+1, der)
    }
  }
```

**Segundo consejo**: evita usar variables siempre que puedas.

Ahora ponemos todo junto:

```scala
def busquedaBinariaRec[A](x:A, xs:Array[A])(implicit ord : Ordering[A]): Option[Int] = {
  import ord._

  def buscar(izq: Int, der: Int): Option[Int] = {
    if (izq > der)
      None
    else{
      val cen = (izq + der)/2
      val y = xs(cen)
      if (x == y)
        Some(cen)
      else if (x < y) 
        buscar(izq, cen-1)
      else
        buscar(cen+1, der)
      }
    }

  buscar(0, xs.length-1)
}
```

La última sentencia es la que ejecuta la función recursiva y devuelve el resultado.

Puede que quede más claro con el método `compare`:

```scala
def busquedaBinariaRec[A](x:A, xs:Array[A])(implicit ord : Ordering[A]): Option[Int] = {
  import ord._

  def buscar(izq: Int, der: Int): Option[Int] = {
    if (izq > der)
      None
    else{
      val cen = (izq + der)/2
      compare(x, xs(cen)) match {
        case 0 => Some(cen)
        case -1 => buscar(izq, cen-1)
        case 1 => buscar(cen+1, der)
      }
    }
  }

  buscar(0, xs.length-1)
}
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias! Todo muy bien explicado y lo he entendido a la perfección. De nuevo mil gracias!!